# Do https enable web sites sent cookies over an encrypted channel?

Tags: encryption, tls, cookies

Do HTTPS enabled web sites send cookies over an encrypted channel and if yes are this still vulnerable to session hijacking attacks?

Answer (score 7):

If you request a page using HTTPS, yes, the cookies (and virtually everything else) is delivered over an encrypted channel.

***However*** that does not mean that there are no avenues for attack.  If the cookies are not marked with the "secure" flag, they will *also* be sent over HTTP, and will be exposed on any HTTP request to the site, even if it merely causes the site to redirect you to the HTTPS version of the page.  This can be mitigated by setting the secure flag so the cookies are only sent along with HTTPS requests.

Additionally, if cookies aren't marked with the HttpOnly flag, they're potentially exposed if there are XSS vulnerabilities on the site.  Cookies that aren't marked at HttpOnly can be read by JavaScript on a page, and if the JavaScript is injected by an attacker and malicious, the cookies could be extracted and forwarded.

So, while using HTTPS is one piece of the security solution, it isn't the only piece.

Comment: I see. So to attempt to perform a session hijacking attack I would have to place myself first somehow between the victim and possibly his local router to sniff the traffic. I could accomplish this via ARP spoof to fake  the MAC address of the router to route the traffic trough my host and then through the router. So if the site is served via HTTPS and the secure flag is set (I assume this is done by the server) I'm out of luck, correct (because AFAIK cookies are transferred in HTTP request/response packets).

Comment: @adam86 Correct.

Comment: So, an session hijacking attack could take really place if cookies are transfered via HTTP, right?

Comment: @adam86 Yes.  If the cookies aren't marked as secure, and you make an HTTP request, they will be sent, and a passive attacker could harvest them and use them to take over the session.

Comment: So just to confirm: a) if the web site is HTTPS only (it does not serve any content via HTTP) all cookies will be encrypted as they are transmitted in the HTTP requestes/responses, correct ? b) in case when the web site is serving content via HTTPS and HTTP one should configure the server to always send cookies with the "secure" flag set so that it will always enforce having sent them via an encrypted channel, correct ?

Answer (score 1):

No and yes. Session hijacking attempts will not be able to steal the cookie directly out of the TLS encrypted web request, but this does not prevent them from guessing the cookie (brute forcing), performing a timing attack against the request's encryption to find the data (assuming the implementation for TLS did not include blinding functions), or acquiring it via an XSS attack.

I'm sure I forgot some other ways, but that would be my basic line of thought if I wanted to acquire your cookies.